# Not able to login - User has no password set

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I don't want to use `accounts-ui` or `accounts-ui-unstyled`, only `accounts-password`, thus I decided to use the Accounts and Meteor methods.
I create a user with the following code (client):

```
Accounts.createUser({
        email: email,
        emails: [{address: email, verified: false}],
        password: password,
        profile: {
            name: name
        }
    }, function(err) { ... });
```

which seems to be working fine, however when I try to create do a login with this code (client):

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Doesn't matter if the password is correct or not it always replies: `Error: User has no password set [403]`.

Meteor version: 1.4.2.3

Comment: Why don't you provide `username` when creating the user? And what's the `emails` array that you pass? It will be ignored.

Comment: I want to use only email, however I tried with `username: email` and didn't work either. The emails arrays is for multiple email addresses.

Comment: There is no point in supplying the emails array to the method. The user should be automatically logged-in when created from the client. Anyway, I am not sure where you used `username: email`.

Comment: True, emails should be done automatically by the server. It seems that the problem as on the server side, I had inverted the user with the options: `Accounts.onCreateUser(function (user, options)` rather than `Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user)`. If you want place it as a response and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Nah, just delete the question :)